# Нужна помощь с построением иерархии данных и коллекциями для представления макета солнечной системы

Tags: java, коллекции

Доброго времени суток! Очень нужна помощь и совет опытного человека с выбором нужной коллекции, и правильного представления иерархии данных.

**Концепт такой:** есть некая **космическая империя**, которая **состоит из звездных систем**, во главе которых стоят непосредственно **звезды**(может быть одна или несколько, поэтому империи состоят именно из систем, а не звезд), с разным количеством **планет**, вокруг которых **могут вращаться спутники**, и на которых могут(или нет) **находиться космические станции и колонии**.
На данный момент реализовал такую иерархию:

На вершине иерархии объект класса Star, который содержит константы, поля и **список планет** этой звезды вида

```
public class Star extends AstrObject {
    public final String objectTYPE = "Star";
    public String starCLASS;

    // Все планеты звезды храняться здесь
    public ArrayList<Planet> planets = new ArrayList<>();
```

этот список содержит объекты класса Planet, который, в свою очередь, содержит уже **список спутников** этой планеты

```
public class Planet extends AstrObject {
    public final String objectTYPE = "Planet";

    // Все спутники планеты храняться здесь
    public ArrayList<Sputnik> sputniks = new ArrayList<>();
    // Все станции и колонии планеты
    public LinkedList<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
    public LinkedList<Colony> colonies = new LinkedList<>();
```

так же у объектов классов Planet и Sputnik есть **списки станций и колоний** соответствующих классов, которые могут присутствовать или нет:

```
   LinkedList<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
   LinkedList<Colony> colonies = new LinkedList<>();
```

Определение принадлежности созданных объектов происходит по такой схеме:

```
// Определение принадлежности планет
star1.planets.add(planet1);
star1.planets.add(planet2);
star1.planets.add(planet3);
star1.planets.add(planet4);     

// Определение принадлежности спутников
planet3.sputniks.add(sputnik1);
planet4.sputniks.add(sputnik2);
planet4.sputniks.add(sputnik3);

// Определение принадлежности станций
planet3.stations.add(st1);
planet4.stations.add(st2);

// Определение принадлежности колоний 
sputnik1.colonies.add(col1);
planet4.colonies.add(col2);
```

Очень долго выбирал, какую из коллекций нужно использовать, выбирал из вариантов **LinkedHashSet** (*т.к солнечная система похожа на множество уникальных объектов*), **LinkedHashMap**(*вроде как ключ - Звезда, значение - планета; ключ - планета, значение - спутник и тд*), и **ArrayList**, на котором и остановился из-за возможности поиска объектов по индексу.
Сама **структура данных отображается правильно** и показывает звезду, планеты этой звезды, спутники этих планет(если они есть) и колонии со станциями, но это только сверху вниз. ***Проблемы начинаются, когда нужно узнать информацию снизу вверх***, то есть на каком спутнике находится колония, вокруг какой планеты вращается этот спутник, какой звезде принадлежит планета и тд.

Отсюда, собственно, вопросы:
***1) Правильно ли представлена иерархия данных для данного проекта, и если неправильно, то
2) Какой максимально эффективный способ представления иерархии данных нужно использовать? Какую коллекцию следует применить?
3)Возможно ли правильно и эффективно реализовать метод getLocation(), который возвращал бы местоположение объекта от меньшего к большему? (сначала планета, потом спутник, потом звезда и тд).***

p.s. Большое спасибо за внимание, надеюсь воды не слишком много..

Comment: Мне кажется все это в определенной степени "дело вкуса". Первое что пришло в голову - почему класс Star включает в себя коллекцию Planets? На мой взгляд корректнее ввести класс StarSystem (вроде Солнечная система). Он бы включал в себя и звезду и планеты. Тогда если у Вас появится необходимость реализовать к примеру "двойные звезды"  это будет сделать проще. Но это теория, а на практике это "утяжеляет" иерархию ваших игровых объектов, и возможно вовсе не нужно, поскольку система у Вас содержит только одну звезду.

Comment: Прошу прощения что не по теме, пожалуйста замените sputniks на satellites. Очень режет глаз :)

Comment: На заметку.Используйте отношение is-a и has-a.is a - Является чем-то,кем-то. has-a содержит что-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас хорошая стройная система, но на мой взгляд ее можно немного доработать и упростить, установив необходимые связи. andreyLv в комментарии правильно отметил, самый верхний класс логичнее сделать StarSystem, в который внести звезды.

Практически каждый объект в вашей вселенной обладает некими свойствами. Он имеет название, вокруг него могут вращаться какие то другие объекты, и он сам движется  по орбите вокруг каких то одного или нескольких объектов. Соответственно базовым классом для построения можно сделать `abstract class AstrObject`. У него должно быть имя, коллекция объектов на его орбите и коллекция объектов, на орбите вокруг которых он сам вращается. Коллекцию лучше выбрать `Set`, чтобы не было двух одинаковых объектов, или `Map<Name, Astro Object>`, чтобы объекты было легко искать по имени. Дополните базовый класс полезными методами, общими для всех объектов, например GetLocation().

Унаследуйте все объекты от абстрактного AstrObject и дополните их полезными свойствами, характерными каждому виду объектов. Например в StarSystem можно добавить общий список объектов в системе, чтобы не могло появиться две одинаковых Луны одновременно на орбите Земли и Марса.

Рыба базового класса:

```
    abstract class AstrObject {
    String name;
    Map<String, AstrObject> location;
    Map<String, AstrObject> sats;

    public AstrObject GetLocation() {
        return location.keySet().stream()
                .map(name -> location.get(name))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
    }
}
```

Какие поля сделать приватными или публичными, какими методами наполнить - на вкус и цвет